# Add custom field to WordPress Post for impleCode Products

Tags: wordpress

I am using the impleCode Catalog plugin to create a store on my website.

I'd like to add a "Cost Price" field to products so I can put what I pay for each product instead of just the sale price.

Is it possible to add a custom field to WordPress Posts where I can store this information?

I cannot find much online about doing it for an existing plugin so seeking some advice.